# Unwanted \r in perl cron script

Tags: linux, cron

I've been to the edge of the internet and on support lines trying to figure this out to no avail:

I'm trying to set up a cron job so my RackSpace Cloud site gets backup up. There are plenty of examples to use but I can't seem to get any of them to work because it appends '\r' to the end of all my lines. I've tried a couple of editors like notepad and notepad++ but nothing changes. Here is an example of my backup.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

webroot='/mnt/example/123456/www.mysite.com/web/content/'
backuproot='/mnt/example/123456/www.mysite.com/backup'

###################
# Backup Database #
###################
mysqldump -h my.database.host -u my_username -p'my_password' my_database_name > $backuproot/db_backup.sql

###############
# Backup Site #
###############
tar -czpvf $backuproot/site_backup.tar.gz $webroot
```

An example of the errors I get:

```
tar: /mnt/example/123456/www.mysite.com/web/content/\r\r: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: /mnt/example/123456/www.mysite.com/backup\r/site_backup.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

For some reason the script is considering the '\r' as part of the command and I'm not sure how to avoid that. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are editors for Windows which can handle Linux-style line endings, eg EditPad.

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks! Also, after trying EditPad and knowing what to search for I found out that Notepad++ supports this too (Edit > EOL Coversion).

Comment: Thanks DM and MRAB. Used Notepad++ just then to fix a similar problem that I was having. Can confirm that this is the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Any reason in particular this is tagged Perl?

At any rate, I'm guessing that you're editing on Windows, then trying to execute on a Linux machine.  The command `dos2unix` should convert line endings so that you don't have this problem.

Comment: You're right, I am on Windows and trying to execute on a Linux machine. I don't have access to run dos2unix on the linux machine but thanks for the response and tip.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the line endings in your file.

Under Windows, lines in a file are ended with the characters CR+LF (\r\n).  Under unix, the carriage return isn't used, so they just end with the LF (\n).

You'll need to change the type of line ending you're using - with Notepad++, you can change the format of the file via the Edit menu (look for something like Unix Format, Unix line endings, etc).

If you want to learn ALL about line endings, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline.